# Compilando cliente zookeeper em uma maquina solaris, erro no libtool

Tags: shell

Estou tentando compilar o cliente `zookeeper 3.4.12c` em uma máquina `solaris`, abaixo estão os passos que segui.

1. descompactar o código fonte, entrar na pasta zookeeper-x.x.x/src/c.
2. fazer um "./configure [OPTIONS]" para gerar os makes

Mas o processo trava no passo dois, com o seguinte erro:

```
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC    --mode=link gcc  -Wall -Werror -g -O2
-D_GNU_SOURCE -no-undefined -version-info 2 -lnsl -lsocket -export-symbols-regex '(zoo_|zookeeper_|zhandle|Z|format_log_message|log_message|logLevel|deallocate_|allocate_|zerror|is_unrecoverable)'
-o libzookeeper_st.la -rpath /usr/local/lib  libzkst.la libhashtable.la libtool: link: /bin/nm -p   ./.libs/libzkst.a ./.libs/libhashtable.a |  | /bin/gsed 's/.* //' | sort | uniq > .libs/libzookeeper_st.exp ./libtool[1732]: eval: syntax error at line 1: `|' unexpected
*** Error code 3 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `libzookeeper_st.la'
```

O que está faltando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta executar o `./configure` com os parametros abaixo, esses arquivos são necessários para o `zookeeper` e aparentemente não estão sendo linkados automaticamente no seu configure.

```
... ./.libs/libzkst.a ./.libs/libhashtable.a |  | /bin/gsed 's/.* //' ...
```